# Colors missing when building my project Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I recently started implementing a cellular automaton in unity and now I'm trying to build the project but the colors, which got displayed in the editor demo: [image]
are not displayed properly after building: [image]
I implemented the color with:

`CubeMeshes[cubeMeshesIndex][gen].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = ColorsArr[color]`
where ColorsArr[color] is e.g. `Color.blue`

My always included shader list looks like this:[image]

What exactly am I missing?

Edit: I was able to solve this by running the script and checking which shaders are added on the material during runtime when i click on the instantiated object in the Hierarchy. For me it was the "standard" shader which I then added to the "Always included Shaders" list as the 8th option.

Comment: Looks like you might be missing shaders. Check the project/graphics settings to add them to the always include list.

Comment: which shader exactly should i add? I've updated my question with my current always included shaders

Comment: you got lucky. when i build and get this error, the UI is broken too. i posted an answer that fixes it all below.

Answer (score 1):

i have this error with all of my projects, and it has nothing to do with shaders. you just click on the gear icon in the top right corner of your player settings, and press reset. then, you can add the title and other options again, and it will work. good luck!

EDIT: maybe try resetting the graphics settings as well.

Comment: sadly that didn't fix my game, maybe those are two different bugs because your UI is broken as well? Thanks for the help tho!

Comment: i added an eddit. if it still doesn't work, ill change this to a wiki post so others can add new solutions that work no matter what the reason for error is.

Comment: I was able to fix this, I added my procedere to my question as an Edit. I appreciate your help, I searched alot of forums and I think there are many different things that can cause the pink shaders,

Comment: glad you were able to find an answer. i know from experience that this problem is really annoying. since it's fixed, you should probably close the question.